# asp-validation-summary div displaying even without errors

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, tag-helpers

This is my page. [image: My page]

The red box is the validation summary div

I use taghelpers and the div looks like this

```
<div asp-validation-summary="ValidationSummary.All" class="validation-summary alert alert-danger"></div>
```

Is there any way to only display this div if the user has pressed the button ?

I've tried hiding it and then showing it using jquery when the button is pushed, but because the page reloads it stays hidden even after.

My page is in ASP.Net 5 MVC 6.

Comment: Share your action result code.

Comment: Have you solved this issue? I seem to have the same problem using .NET Core, and the solution below does not work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

wrapping it in an if statement fixed it

```
@if (!ViewData.ModelState.IsValid)
{
<div asp-validation-summary="ValidationSummary.All" class="validation-summary alert alert-danger"></div>
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't help if you're testing a child model/view as the ModelState object is for whole model. The div would still be rendered if the model failed validation elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS class .validation-summary-valid

```
.validation-summary-valid {  
    display: none;  
}
```